# Generate unique number upto 2^32 and maintaining free and allocated numbers for reuse

Tags: boost

I want to generate a running binary number( kind of ID) and I have requirement to maintain numbers which are being freed and I would like to use 32 bits to generate unique number and when exhausted would like to use ID which are being freed. I was thinking of maintaining dynamic_bitset of 2^32-1 to maintain allocation/deallocation status but not sure if I can have this big size

Answer (score 0):

Quick napkin calculations:

```
(2^32) * bit = approx. 536.87091 megabytes
```

So, do you have half a gigabyte to spare?

Comment: memory is ok but just wondering if dynamic_bitset of this size is too CPU intensive. I would like something which doesn't consume too much CPU.

Comment: Actually my requirement is 2^21-1, not 2^32-1, gave 2^32-1 for ease.

Comment: So... You only give a number (2^32) and then wonder about size ("I can have this big size?"). Now you start asking about performance. Memory doesn't consume CPU at all. You're not _doing anything witth it_, so performance is irrelevant.

Comment: The nicer way to say this would be "it depends on what you're doing with the bitset". For many loads bitsets are pretty much the thing to beat. But, yeah, do file a better question, one which indicates the goal.

Answer (score 0):

Your simplest option for creating unique values is to just use the memory allocator:

```
// the id type
typedef std::intptr_t id_t;

// allocate a unique id
id_t alloc_id() { return reinterpret_cast<id_t>(::operator new(1)); }

// free an id
void free_id(id_t id) { ::operator delete(reinterpret_cast<void*>(id)); }
```

Comment: I guess your program can give me unique ID but my problem is different. I want to keep a track of freeId which I can use once I exhaust 2^32-1 and I know in between there were few Id whose whose object( I am giving this Id to object) are being deleted so basically when I delete a object, I want to mark somewhere those Ids which are ready to be reused for that I was thinking of bitset so I know hich Ids can be given to new objects.